# Running Python Scripts in Django and displaying responses

Tags: python, django

I am creating a Django site that integrates into the UniFi controller, I have managed to get a script working that uses the pyunifi package, what I want to do is be able to execute this script from within Django and display the responses on a page within the site.

Currently the script can run on it's own and can output the data I want into the terminal.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to show the `print` outputs from the script or show the returned variables?

Comment: Want to show the print outputs from the script please, so what it spits out on the terminal console I want to display on the page. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Call the script in your view, and pass what ever it returns to the response, which would pass it to the template

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is going to be such a dumb question but what is the best way to go about importing this etc? This is really new ground to me been looking at various articles online about importing an external script into Django but nothing particularly clear on how this is done. File is called unifi.py stored in a folder called unifi within the app's directory